# My theme song doesn't start and loop correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a video game in Unity and I want to play an intro `AudioSource Intro` when the game starts, and then loop the main theme of the level.

It works but the problem that I am having is that when finishing the intro there is silence of 1 second and it begins to reproduce the theme. 
This silence also appears when the theme ends and loops, which makes the feeling that the game freezes for a second.

```
public class audioTheme : MonoBehaviour
{

    public AudioSource Intro;
    private bool startedLoop;

    void Start()
    {
        Intro = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Intro.Play();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!Intro.isPlaying && !startedLoop)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("theme");
            startedLoop = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have an "AudioManager" script which has an array of audios, such as jump sound effects, coins and the main theme. This allows me to use any sound using the statement `FindObjectOfType <AudioManager> (). Play (" soundName ");`

```
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sound[] sounds;

    void Awake()
    {    
        foreach (Sound s in sounds)
        {
            s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            s.source.clip = s.clip;
            s.source.volume = s.volume;
            s.source.loop = s.loop;
            s.source.pitch = s.pitch;
        }        
    }

    public void Play(string name)
    {
        Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
        s.source.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: And there's not a second of silence at the beginning or the end of the audio file?

Comment: did you check that the audio file itself doesn't have silence at the start or the end of it? you can use a free program called "audacity" to check that out

Comment: Thanks for answer! I already checked the audio and it loops perfectly when i put it with out the intro.
I used "Bosca Ceoil" to make the music and the program exports "in grid" to avoid this problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common reason of such behaviour is using mp3 format for music instead of wav. Mp3 have short silence at front and can't be used for looping. Use mp3 for short sounds and wav for looped sounds and music. Also you can check [following answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/343057/how-do-i-make-unity-seamlessly-loop-my-background.html).

Comment: Thanks so much! i will check that answer And thanks for the information, I use wav for the theme and effects, so i will change to mp3 in FX to try if its work better.